# User input matrix but wrong output using phython

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, matrix

so basically, I want to make an automatic matrix input and generate the output but the second part of the input shows up with the same output as the first one. is there any wrong logic behind my code? here's my code (im sorry for bad english):

```
    #input menu 2 :
def prgmatriks2() :
  ct = 2
 
  for a in range(ct):

    m = int (input("input row "+str (a)+": "))
    n = int (input("input column"+str (a)+": "))

  # initialization matriks
  matrix = [] 
  print("Matriks input:  ") 

  #Input : 
  for x in range(ct) :
      for i in range(m):          #rows loop
          a =[] 
          for j in range(n):      #column loop
            a.append(int(input())) 
          matrix.append(a) 
    # Print Matriks
  for x in range(ct) :  
      for i in range(m): 
          for j in range(n): 
              print(matrix[i][j], end = " ") 
          print()
```

and for the output:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXCkz.png)

text version:

```
Pilihan menu(1-2): 
2
input row 0: 2
input column0: 2
input row 1: 2
input column1: 2
Matriks input:  
3
2
4
1
6
5
2
1
3 2 
4 1 
3 2 
4 1
```

instead generate :

```
3 2
4 1

6 5
2 1
```

the program repeat the first output :

```
3 2 
4 1 
3 2 
4 1
```

Comment: Note that you overwrite the first `m` and `n` when you go through the loop again, so you throw away the first set.  Try entering `99  99 2 2` and you'll see it will still ask for 8 items.  Also, you aren't entering two matrices here, you are just making one long matrix, 2x4.  If `column0` is not the same as `column1`, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

`print(matrix[i][j], end=" ")` replace here `i` with `i+x*n`.

---

So logic for printing Matrices will be like this code :

```
# Print Matrices 
for x in range(ct):
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
            print(matrix[x*n+i][j], end=" ")
        print()
    print()
print(matrix)
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
3 2
4 1

6 5
2 1
```

Comment: Actually, it needs to be `x*n+i`.  You need to skip over the whole first array.

Comment: Thanks @TimRoberts this was just typing mistake